# Neuroph OCR- Handwriting Recognition Library in Android Project

Tags: ocr

I am working on a project on handwriting recognition in Android Studio. 
From online source Neuroph OCR seems is the best to recognise hand-written char.

My input is a list of x,y coordinate and draw them in line using opencv drawline function

then create an image showing the char 
the image can be recognised by hand-written OCR.

Anyone can have some instructions or example or source how can i use this library?
i only know it is a useful library but seldom find any example